# Unknown Conversion Type Character `"'

Tags: c, compilation, makefile

I have the follow line of C code:

```
sprintf (ptr, "<th width=\"25%\">Head One</th>\n");
```

I have tried combinations of replacements:

- Replacing: `\"` with `""`
- Replacing `%` with `%%`

But on compilation, using a Makefile, all produce the same error:

```
warning: unknown conversion type character `"' in format
```

Any suggestions on how to avoid this please?

Comment: try `sprintf (ptr, "<th width=\"25%%\">Head One</th>\n");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use `strcpy()` since you don't want formatting (or `strlcpy()`/`strcpy_s()` for safety).
- Doubling the percent should work, and if you get *the same* error then that of course points at something being wrong in your build environment.